# derived class has parent private attributes

Tags: c#, inheritance, .net-4.5

Got a problem with simple inheritance. The problem is very simple:

I have a `Parent Form` with name `MainForm` derived from `System.Windows.Forms.Form`.

```
MainForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
```

And the second `ChildForm` is derived from `MainForm`.

```
ChildForm : MainForm
```

`MainForm` has nothing but a button on it, which is obviously `private` for this class. The button calls `ChildForm`.

[image]

But after creating `ChildForm` it also has that button on it, and i can't do any thing with that. It is not even on design panel, but when i run the application, it also works and calls `ChildForm`. I couldn't figure it out at all...

[image]

So how can i remove it from `ChildForm` and keep it on its place? and why private member is being shown out of its scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not being shown out of its scope at all. When you create an instance of the ChildForm you also get an instance of the MainForm complete with its bits and pieces - like the button. The 'private' scope simply affects how you can access that button at development time, i.e. you cannot access it programmatically from outside the form's class.

What you need to do is create a public or protected property where you can set the visibility of the button from the child form. In the child form you can toggle (set) that property to the desired default value, a good place for this is in a constructor or form initialisation routine. Depending on which UI technology you are using you can bind the visibility of the button directly to the property, or you can programmaktically set the button's property when the form's property changes.

Comment: If it creates an instance then why I can't delete it? or why i can't even move it? and kindly more clear your last words `you can override the property in the child form and default it to false or hidden`

Comment: @Shaharyar You can hide the button, but it needs to be done from within the MainForm (as the button is private and therefore not accessible from outside the main form). I've updated my answer a bit for you.

Comment: Well !! very nice answer. I made it `protected` and `disposed` it in the `ChildForm` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Why does child form need to inherit from main form? From what I understand, Main form has a button which creates a child form instance and displays it. If you end up disabling the **only** thing on the form there really isn't any point in inheriting from it then...

I would just make ChildForm its own form (inheriting from System.Windows.Forms.Form instead of MainForm), this will remove the button from the ChildForm, and stop you having to make the button on MainForm public/protected.

Comment: My application is currently under development. I have to create more and more methods which i will need to call in other derived classes.

Comment: Sure, but there are other ways to achieve this. If you are wanting to call logic that exists only in main form, that is a sign to refactor your mainform and expose it (in another class). Inheritance is one way to do it, but I do not think it will be the best way to do it.